# Using CDATA in html leaves the brackets at the end for iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, parsing

I have a simple `html` snippet that loks like this:

```
let mystring = """
            <![CDATA[
            <body>
                <font size=+2>
                <p><b>Before proceeding:</b></p>
                <ul type="dash">
                    <li>Save a backup copy of the door configuration file</li><li>Disconnect all other Bluetooth devices</li></ul><br />
                <p><b>During upgrade:</b></p>
                <ul type="dash">
                    <li>Do not turn off phone screen, take calls, use other apps, or in any other way push the app to the background</li>
                </ul><br />
                <p><b>Are you sure you want to upgrade %1$@ firmware?</b></p>
                </font>
                </body>]]>
            """
```

I parse it like this:

```
var htmlToAttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
    guard let data = String(format: mystring, doorName).data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And it ends up like this (note the ]]> at the end):

[image]

Why are the `brackets` still there at the end while everything else works fine? It works fine when testing for `Android` and it's also for the sake of `Android` that `CDATA` is used in the first place. How do I make this work for `iOS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that CDATA is xml and not html and that is why `NSAttributedString` can't handle it properly. Unfortunately your string is not a proper xml string so we can't use `XMLParser` for this.

One way is to strip out the xml (CDATA) from the string using a regular expression

```
let htmlString = mystring.replacingOccurrences(of: "(<\\!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]>)", 
                                               with: "", 
                                               options: .regularExpression)
   .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```